# Trying to call methods from gems in a view, getting "no such file" error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have just installed a base installation of rails and have edited the main page to view some basic html and a link to create a new blog post via ruby in the corresponding 'erb' file.  I am trying to add some additional ruby commands on this same page via <%= %> tags.

```
<h1>Hello, Rails!</h1> <%= link_to "My Blog", posts_path %>

<p>
<%= require 'rubygems' %>
<%= require 'simplegeo' %>

<%= SimpleGeo::Client.set_credentials('token', 'secret') %>
<%= a = SimpleGeo::Client.get_context(coordinates,coordinates); a %>
</p>
```

When I load this page , I get the following error: no such file to load -- simplegeo

Can someone point me in the right direction?  Many thanks!

Comment: You probably shouldn't be requiring gems in your views. Try keeping most of your logic in the Controller, and just displaying it in the View.

Comment: Possible to show me an example of doing this?

Comment: "Simple Ruby/rails question" isn't a useful title - every question here is a question, and the tags ruby-on-rails and ruby indicates it's about Rails or Ruby.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Rails 3, you need to add this gem to your "Gemfile" .. follow this: http://gembundler.com/rails3.html

Remove this completely.. Never do this in your views

```
<%= require 'rubygems' %>
<%= require 'simplegeo' %>
```

Once you restart your rails server, if you added "simplegeo" to your gemfile, it'll be auto-required.

Move this to your controller to start

```
SimpleGeo::Client.set_credentials('token', 'secret')
@simple_geo_client = SimpleGeo::Client.get_context(coordinates,coordinates)
```

Then in your view, you can access any variable that starts with @

To get started in Rails, check out http://railsforzombies.org/

Answer (score 1):

In rails 3.x, you use [Bundler](http://gembundler.com/) to specify gems. No need to require, especially in views.

Correct way is:

Open Gemfile
Set/List required gems inside using format:

```
source :rubygems
gem "simplegeo"
gem "some_other_gem"
```

Run `bundle install` (or just `bundle`) command in console.

now restart your server and gems are auto required.

Check out [Rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) on how to start.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you did not install Simplegeo gem properly, or did not attach it correctly in you IDE.

Comment: Assuming you installed rubygems, as described [here](http://rubygems.org/pages/download) - `gem install simplegeo` from console.